# Checking number of connections to Oracle using a shell

Tags: shell, oracle11g

I'm running Oracle 11g on Centos 5.5.

I want to know how many connections to Orcl DB by using shell script.
In shell script: I think I will create many "connections" to DB and I will count them.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
c=1
while [ $c -le 100 ]
do
sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF
exit;
EOF
        (( c++ ))
        ((count++))
done
echo "**************************************"
echo $count
```

Can you share me some ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Now, I try to test by using fork() in linux , to multiply p

Comment: Solved. I solve with c programming + sqlapi (instead of bash shell - difficult to me).  I tested with BenmarkFactory and my script.c . It's  same.